# C# - Delegates and BackgroundWorkers

Tags: c#, multithreading, methods, delegates, backgroundworker

I'm new to C# and object-oriented programming in general. I have an application which parses the text files.

By default, the program executes on the main thread and thus the application freezes until execution.

I have 5 void methods which take in a list of `string` as parameter.

Based on the various `CheckBox` options, these 5 void methods get executed in combinations.

The `BackgroundWorker` performs the operation on a different thread. Thus, the application does not freeze.

However, I would require 15+ `BackgroundWorkers` for every combination.

The following is my code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    List<string> textFiles = new List<string>();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void mParsing(List<string> textFiles) { /* parsing logic */ }
    public void iParsing(List<string> textFiles) { /* parsing logic */ }
    public void aParsing(List<string> textFiles) { /* parsing logic */ }
    public void qParsing(List<string> textFiles) { /* parsing logic */ }

    public void Summary()
    {
        // Logic to generate summary   
    }

    private void btnGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (checkM.Checked == true && checkI.Checked == false && checkA.Checked == false && checkQ.Checked == false)
        {
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
        else if (checkM.Checked == true && checkI.Checked == true && checkA.Checked == false && checkQ.Checked == false)
        {
            backgroundWorker2.RunWorkerAsync();
        }            

        //So On....
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        mParsing(textFiles);
        Summary();
    }
    private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("View Summary?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
        if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            string summary = filepath;
            Process.Start("notepad.exe", summary);
        } 
    }
    private void backgroundWorker2_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        mParsing(textFiles);
        iParsing(textFiles);
        Summary();
    }
    private void backgroundWorker2_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("View Summary?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
        if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            string summary = filepath;
            Process.Start("notepad.exe", summary);
        }
    }
}
```

The `Func<>` does not accept void datatype and I am having a bad time understanding the delegates and multi threading.

My problem is, I don't know how to avoid multiple background workers. Can this be implemented with help of delegates?

**Update:** .NET Framework Version: 4.0

Comment: Are you using backgroundworker just because thats the first way you discovered to do multithreading and you stuck with it? Or for some specific reason? I ask because its a bit of an outdated way to deal with threading. And as you've discovered its overly complex.

Comment: @Jamiec, I used background worker because I have used it in past with VB.NET application. The mentioned methods require to run in the sequence. How can this be achieved? Also, explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: RunWorkerAsync() allows you to pass an argument to DoWork.  Clearly you'll have a good use for it here, one BGW is enough.

Comment: @Hans but I need to pass multiple methods to the DoWork. It wont allow me to pass  backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(mParsing(textFiles),  Summary());

Comment: It allows you to pass *any* object.  Just create your own little class, it can have as many fields as you need.  Which methods you'll call ought to be in the DoWork code.  But you can declare a field of that class as a delegate if that is handy for some reason.

Comment: ".NET Framework Version: 4.0" Why? This is **7 years old** now. Think about where you were and what you were doing 7 years ago, and then ask yourself honestly why you are supporting such an ancient technology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coolerfarmer's answer works well with .NET 4.5.

However, Due to .NET 4.0 limitations, Managed to achieve asynchronous executions with help of threads & delegates

It may not be an efficient way of performing the combination execution of methods.

What I did was, created an individual method with execution order and used the following code:

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    List<string> textFiles = new List<string>();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void mParsing(List<string> textFiles) { /* parsing logic */ }
    public void iParsing(List<string> textFiles) { /* parsing logic */ }
    public void aParsing(List<string> textFiles) { /* parsing logic */ }
    public void qParsing(List<string> textFiles) { /* parsing logic */ }

    public void Summary()
    {
        // Logic to generate summary   
    }

    private void btnGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (checkM.Checked == true && checkI.Checked == false && checkA.Checked == false && checkQ.Checked == false)
        {
            Thread worker = new Thread(mOption);
                if (!worker.IsAlive)
                {

                    worker.Start();
                    frm.Show(); // Displaying Form - Performing Operation.. Please Wait... 
                    btn1.Enabled = false;
                }
        }
        else if (checkM.Checked == true && checkI.Checked == true && checkA.Checked == false && checkQ.Checked == false)
        {
            Thread worker = new Thread(miOption);
                if (!worker.IsAlive)
                {

                    worker.Start();
                    frm.Show(); // Displaying Form - Performing Operation.. Please Wait... 
                    btn1.Enabled = false;
                }
        }            

        //So On....
    }


        private void mOption()
        {
            mParsing(textFiles);
            Summary();

            MethodInvoker inv = delegate
            {
                frm.Hide();

        DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("View Summary?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
        if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            string summary = filepath;
            Process.Start("notepad.exe", summary);
        } 
                this.btn1.Enabled = true;

            };
            this.Invoke(inv);
        }

        private void miOption()
        {
            mParsing(textFiles);
            iParsing(textFiles);
            Summary();

            MethodInvoker inv = delegate
            {
                frm.Hide();

        DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("View Summary?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
        if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            string summary = filepath;
            Process.Start("notepad.exe", summary);
        } 
                this.btn1.Enabled = true;

            };
            this.Invoke(inv);
        }

}
```

Any inputs with explanation are most welcome and Thank you all for the inputs and suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

In C# there is async/await which is exactly what you need.
Take this example:

```
private async void btnGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (checkM.Checked == true && checkI.Checked == false && checkA.Checked == false && checkQ.Checked == false)
    {
        await mParsing(textFiles);
        DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("View Summary?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
        if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            string summary = filepath;
            Process.Start("notepad.exe", summary);
        } 
    }
}
```

For this to work both functions, `btnGo_Click` and `mParsing` must have the keyword async in it's definition. In addition the return type of the parsing function must be changed to Task.

```
public async Task mParsing(List<string> textFiles)
{
    //Method containing parsing logic
}
```

Moreover you need some changes to your (now async) mParsing function. 
E.g. blocking calls like `new WebClient().DownloadString(url)` must be replaced with non blocking calls `new WebClient().DownloadStringTaskAsync(url)`

As there's not always a non blocking call available you can also use `Task.Run()`:

```
public async Task mParsing(List<string> textFiles)
{
    await Task.Run(() => {
        //Do blocking calls
    });
}
```

Comment: Hello Coolerfarmer, 
Unfortunately, I am using .NET Framework 4. I cannot change it to the latest one. How can this be implemented without async?